# How to handle escape characters in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update a row in the my SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

The value of the particular column is of type `String`.

The current values in my database is of the form: `NMA`.

But it should be `N'MA`.

My query is:

```
UPDATE mymodifiedtable  
SET FirstName = 'N'MA' 
WHERE receiptNo = '45047603'
```

This is not working for me after googling it.

Pls advice.

I would also like a link where I can learn more on this type of escape characters in SQL Server.

Comment: Did you Google this?  http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sql+server+escape+single+quote gives plenty of useful answers!

Comment: SQL Server has a `String` type?

Comment: todda.speot.is i mean varchar not String.

Comment: Could someone add the answer to close it down?

Comment: @Kane - Could you post your comment as an answer instead so that `ecomma` could answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the quote character to escape quotes. Try SET FirstName = 'N''MA'